# Should I start exercising right away or increase my weight first?

Tags: exercise, weight-gain, muscle-gain

I'm a 26 years old guy and I used to be super skinny until I increased my weight recently by limiting my physical activities and forcing myself to eat more.

Now, my BMI is 19, which is considered "normal", however I'm still close
to being underweight. My goal is to be a little bigger and more muscular.

**My question is**:

1. When should I start working out?
2. Is it better if I continued
   my strategy until I'm 65 kg for example? (FYI: I weigh 56kg now).

Thanks

Comment: You should have started training as soon as you noticed you were underweight. You don't get fit by limiting your physical activity. You get fat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all due respect, you are wasting your time. This weight you are gaining is not the kind of weight you want to gain. As long as you do not train and you do not follow a strict muscle gaining diet all you earn is fat. It may not be visible ([subcutaneous fat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcutaneous_tissue#Subcutaneous_fat)), but it is still there and this kind of fat is even more dangerous ([visceral fat](https://draxe.com/visceral-fat/)).

Don't leave for later what you can do now. Start training as soon as you can and don't be discouraged if you don't see any visible results immediately. I've been like you, about 55kg 4 years ago and now I am 75kg.

You can achieve your goal by following a training schedule that is aims for [muscle mass](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjD9dHo-snNAhUFvhQKHaqMBIMQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reference.com%2Fhealth%2Fmuscle-mass-523607f5a3e9182e&usg=AFQjCNFEuGLPjaNs7QifErRl3kh5CnRkoQ&sig2=TDqL2IDKHftLkbgTFQvw5g). The training routine is different for each body section, but all follow the same rule, High Intensity - Heavy Load. In fact there is also a debate regarding which is better [here](https://www.muscleandstrength.com/articles/volume-vs-high-intensity-which-style-training-best-growth.html), but I like to combine them.

**TIP**: Life has taught me and later I was told by a physician as well, that the number one reason one does not manage to gain muscle mass is the fact that they do not train their legs enough, so be sure to train your legs enough when you actually start.

**One last thing**: I believe it is of vital importance that you know and fully comprehend the significance of avoiding overtraining and its ramifications so when you have time read [this article](http://breakingmuscle.com/strength-conditioning/overtraining-can-kill-you-the-3-stages-of-overtraining-part-1).

Answer (score 1):

1. When should I start working out?

As soon as possible. At 26 you still have the ability to quickly adapt to new exercise and develop muscle relatively easily.

2. Is it better if I continued my strategy until I'm 65 kg for example? (FYI: I weigh 56kg now).

Your weight is just a number that tells you how much of a effect gravity has on you. I suspect what you really care about is how you look. If you want the ever-popular "ripped" physique then you should design a sensible diet plan that has total calories in 15% over your TDEE and has a good macronutrient breakdown (most people suggest 1g protein per 1lb bodyfat). Pair that with a newbie strength workout like Starting Strength or Stronglifts and in 6 months time you should be a little more muscular.